# Dúvida para construir query MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

No meu sistema eu tenho as seguintes tabelas: `tb_partida(id, data_hora, flag_ativo, tb_cotacao_id, tb_campeonato_id)`, `tb_campeonato(id, nome_camp, tb_pais_id) e **tb_pais**(id, nome_pais, tb_continente_id)`.

Pois bem, eu preciso popular um `select` com o país e campeonato das partidas e o `value` sendo o `id` do campeonato `onde tb_partida.flag_ativo = 1`.
Até agora eu tenho o seguinte:

Função:

```
function seleciona_campeonatos_ativos()
{
    $link = conectar();

    $query = "SELECT tb_campeonato.id as id_campeonato, 
      tb_campeonato.nome_camp as nome_campeonato, 
      tb_pais.nome_pais as nome_pais
      FROM tb_campeonato, tb_pais
      WHERE tb_pais.id = tb_campeonato.tb_pais_id";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$registro['id_campeonato']."'>".$registro['nome_pais'].'» '.$registro['nome_campeonato']."</option>";
    }
}
```

Select:

```
<label for="sel1">Filtrar por campeonato:</label>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
    <select style="width: 300px;" class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <?php
            seleciona_campeonatos_ativos();
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Como faço pra exibir somente os campeonatos para os quais há uma partida ativa?

Comment: Já experimentou colocar no final da query "AND tb_partida.flag_ativo = 1" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assim como o [dichrist](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/34995/dichrist) comentou, adicione a condição `WHERE` para a coluna `flag_ativo`:

```
SELECT 
    c.id AS id_campeonato, 
    c.nome_camp AS nome_campeonato, 
    p.nome_pais AS nome_pais
FROM 
    tb_campeonato c
LEFT JOIN  
    tb_pais p ON p.id = c.tb_pais_id
LEFT JOIN  
    tb_partida pt ON pt.tb_campeonato_id = c.id
WHERE 
    pt.flag_ativo = 1
```

Veja no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6db0d8/4)

Comment: Rodei o script que você sugeriu e recebi o seguinte erro: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN tb_pais ON tb_pais.id = tb_campeonato.tb_pais_id
FROM tb_campeonato
' at line 2

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho Corrigi o código e adicionei o exemplo no `sqlfiddle`

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado pela resposta. Realmente tá fazendo o SELECT da maneira que eu queria. Mas ele seleciona o mesmo campeonato duas vezes e isso vai fazer com que mostre o mesmo pais>>campeonato duas ou quantas vezes tiver uma partida que os contenha. Tem como eu limitar pra que cada pais e campeonato só apareça uma vez?

Comment: Tem sim, agrupando os resultados, no final adicione `GROUP BY p.nome_pais`

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez, agora sim ficou da forma que eu queria.